# How to properly make IFNA in array formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Background**

I have a problem where I want to reference a named range and display its values. The range is a list of values, but I don't know beforehand how many elements are in the list. Lets say there are between 1 and 8 values in the list.

My way to go about it is to use an array formula on a 8 long range, and use IFNA() to mask the #N/A output. It is well acceptable that I have some empty space in the output but displaying #N/A does not look so professional. The ISNA doesn't work and I suspect it is because of the array formula changing the ISNA behaviour. Example below in image.

[image: A picture of Microsoft Excel showing my attempt on array formula.]

**Limitations on solution**

The data will be used in PivotTables in a later stage, so simply masking the data as invisible wont do - I really want to not get any #N/A values. Empty string is fine though; empty string is not really a correct answer either, but at least it fails a little more gracefully.

The solution has to be relatively easy to maintain for other people as I'm developing the model for some collegues and they might want to do further changes at a later stage. Therefore I want to avoid very long formulas and extensive use of the name manager.

**Question**

What is the "proper" way to simply array copy"  range of variable size without getting N/A ?

... where "proper" means simple, compact forumla that is easy to maintain and wont carry hidden data in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX instead,  Put this in the first cell of the output and copy down the desired number of rows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(rng_1,ROW(1:1)),"")
```

The ROW(1:1) will iterate as it is copied down pulling te next in the line.  When it runs out it will throw an error and `""` will be put in its place.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I don't like this, since it would prohibit inserting new rows in the sheet. :/ good idea though to use index on the range!

Answer (score 0):

> What is the proper way to simply "array copy" a range of variable size without getting N/A ?

I don't think there is one, but maybe some other methods could work for your issue, such as conditional formatting of the column with the array or using a non-array formula.

[image: Examples of named ranges list solutions]

**Conditional Formatting:**

Conditionally format a column/range to change the formatting of the error cell text to white or whatever blends into your cell color.

[image: Conditional formatting]

**Formula Example:**

Use a non-array formula and have the formula handle the error.

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Pets,ROWS($J$1:J1),COLUMNS($J$1:J1))="","",INDEX(Pets,ROWS($J$1:J1),COLUMNS($J$1:J1))),"")
```

Comment: Conditional formatting wont do since i wish to use the data in a pivot and "invisible" #N/A would show in there. Using the non-formula approach produce very long formulas which are difficult to maintain iif we make changes to the excel model. Ill add those clarifications to the question.

Comment: Fair enough. Hoping you get a good answer to this—interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Scott Craners answer I settled for the following: [image: excel sheet with suggested answer]

It should be slightly less error prone, since the `ROWS`command reference the same area as the output is written to. This way one should not insert rows destroying the formula too badly without realizing it.

Iäm not content with this solution but I guess it will have to do...

Comment: Meta question: should I mark my own answer as "accepted", even though Im not happy with it? I'll leave it non-accepted to indicate I'm open for other solutions.